# a modification of this script in shell

Tags: shell

I have this script that needs to READ ALL fields in a coulmn and validate before it can hit the second column for example

```
Name, City

Joe, Orlando
Sam, Copper Town
Mike, Atlanta
```

so the script should read the entire column of name(top to bottom) and validate for null before it moves to the second column. IT should NOT read line by line . Please add some pointer on how to modify /correct

```
 # Read all files.  no file have spaces in their names


for file in /export/home/*.csv ; do
  # init two variables before processing a new file
 $date_regex = '~(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d~';
 FILESTATUS=GOOD
 FIRSTROW=true
# process file 1 line a time, splitting the line by the
# Internal Field Sep ,
 cat "${file}" | while IFS=, read field1 field2 field3 field4; do
  # Skip first line, the header row

  if [ "${FIRSTROW}" = "true" ]; then
     FIRSTROW=FALSE
     # skip processing of this line, continue with next record
     continue;
  fi

  #different validations
  if [[ ! -n "$field1" ]]; then
  ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi
  #somecheckonField2
      if [[ ! -n "$field2"]]  && ("$field2" =~ $date_regex) ; then
     ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi

      if [[ ! -n "$field3" ]] && (("$field3" != "S") || ("$field3" != "E")); then
     ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi

      if [[ ! -n "$field4" ]] || (( ${#field4} < 9 || ${#field4} > 11 )); then
     ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi


done

 if [ ${FILESTATUS} = "GOOD" ] ; then

  mv ${file} /export/home/goodFile


 else
  mv ${file} /export/home/badFile
fi
```

done

Comment: Unless you store the data from all the fields somewhere processing by column is going to require N reads of the entire file (one per-column). Is there a reason you need to do it this way?

Comment: if the script is checking millions of rows, the time factor helps... if we check an entire column first for bad entries we could find the mistake first and reduce the time it takes for validation

Comment: Unless validating the earlier columns is *orders of magnitude* faster then validating the later columns I don't believe that. The time taken to repeatedly read the entire file from start to finish is a very real amount of time (and work).

Comment: You can't even find the second value in the first column ("Sam") without reading through the entire rest of the first line. Files are linear like that. Unless your lines have a fixed size, in which case you can calculate the start position of the next line. You could, however, possibly just extract the first column via `awk -F, '{print $1}'`. It's still reading the whole thing in the process, though...

Comment: @twalberg would you be able to integrate this in the above script? or give me pointer on aout how to implement awk?

Comment: `man awk`. Wouldn't touch the above script - it has way more problems than just a wrong premise about how to read parts of files... `man bash` might be useful, too..

Comment: i corrected the above script for minor mistakes and made it  work so a sample.csv file is  sent to the goodFile directory however i run into an error like this after its been sent "temp1.sh: line 41: GOOD=BAD: command not found" ... line 41 refers to 4th if condition if($field 4) line immediately after that

Comment: You're assigning the value BAD *not* to the variable FILESTATUS, but to the *value* of the variable FILESTATUS. You need simply `FILESTATUS=BAD`

Comment: @glennjackman is this for just line 41 or do i replace every where i see ${FILESTATUS}=BAD with FILESTATUS=BAD

Comment: replace everywhere `${FILESTATUS}=anything` with `FILESTATUS=anything`

Comment: I have a feeling this could all be one relatively simple `awk` script, but since 1) the representative data doesn't even come close to matching what it appears the script is trying to validate and 2) the script itself is rather unclear and significantly broken and 3) the requirements are not clearly stated, it's a bit difficult to suggest a proper solution.

Comment: @twalberg simply put have 10 csv files in directory, which need to be read in and only will have 4 coulmns all have to be check for null and check for certain condition... if it passes good File directory if it doesn't sent to bad file directory! ... any help would be great! :D thanks

Comment: Unless the data is gigabytes, read the whole file into a 2-dimensional array. Then you can verify column-wise, row-wise, whatever

Comment: will do that but could you provide some kind of skeleton of how this should using awk glennjackman or twalberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk will read the whole file, then you can do your verification in the END block:

```
for file in /export/home/*.csv ; do
    awk -F', ' '
        # skip the header and blank lines
        NR == 1 || NF == 0 {next}

        # save the data
        { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) data[++nr,i] = $i }

        END {
            status = "OK"

            # verify column 1
            for (lineno=1; lineno <= nr; lineno++) {
                if (length(data[lineno,1]) == 0) {
                    status = "BAD" 
                    break
                }
            }
            printf "file: %s, verify column 1, status: %s\n", FILENAME, status

            # verify other columns ...
        }
    ' "$file"
done
```

Comment: thank you for this it will help tremendiously! how would i be able to reach to start my checks on column 2, I.E how/what do i refer to check for the other coulmns?

Comment: Use `data[lineno,2]`, `data[lineno,3]`, etc

Comment: thank you! :)  one last question sir the break in the for..loop. Which loop does it actualy break?

Comment: There's only one loop there.

Comment: i meant for file in /export/home/*.csv ; do 
and

Comment: Ah, no that is an awk "break" -- it cannot affect the loop in the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at an `awk` script that does what it seems like the original script is trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# fields separated by commas
BEGIN { FS = "," }

# skip first line
NR == 1 { next }

# check for empty fields
$1 == "" || $2 == "" || $3 == "" || $4 == "" { exit 1 }

# check for "valid" date (urk... doing this with a regex is horrid)
# it would be better to split it into components and validate each sub-field,
# but I'll leave that as a learning exercise for the reader
$2 !~ /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/ { exit 1 }

# third field should be either S or E
$3 !~ /^[SE]$/ { exit 1 }

# check the length of the fourth field is between 9 and 11
length($4) < 9 || length($4) > 11 { exit 1 }

# if we haven't found problems up to here, then things are good
END { exit 0 }
```

Save that in e.g. `validate.awk`, and set the executable bit on it (`chmod +x validate.awk`), then you can simply do:

```
if validate.awk < somefile.txt
then
  mv somefile.txt goodfiles/
else
  mv somefile.txt badfiles/
fi
```