# script is not hitting any validation steps in awk

Tags: awk, sh

this script is supposed to read in csv in the following format

```
  Name,Date,ID,Number
  John Smith,09/05/2015,s,999-999-99
  Mike Smith,09/06/2015,s,989-979-99
  Fred Smith,09/03/2015,s,781-999-99
```

The first line is a header it is supposed to be skipped. So when script runs every .csv file seems to be moving to the GoodFile direcotory which i think is false positive, i fudged with the validation steps like the 3rd one and entered QE instead of SE(it has to be S or E) it doesn't even hit the code? i am not sure why.. `for(linenum = 1; linenum <nr; linenum++) {
            if (length(dataArr[linenum,3]) == 0){
            printf "Failed 3rd a validation"
            exit 1`

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in test/*.csv ; do

awk -F',' '                       

# skip the header and blank lines
NR = 1 || NF == 0 {next}

#save the data in to a 2d array called dataArr
{ for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) dataArr[++nr,i] = $i }

END {
    STATUS = "GOOD"

    #verify coulmn 1
    for( linenum=1; linenum <= nr; linenum++) {
        if (length(dataArr[linenum,1]) == 0){
        printf "Failed 1st validation"
        exit 1
        }
    }

   printf "file: %s, verify column 1, STATUS: %s\n", FILENAME, STATUS


    #verify coulmn 2
    for(linenum = 1; linenum <nr; linenum++) {
        if (length(dataArr[linenum,2]) == 0){
        printf "Failed 2nd a validation"
        exit 1
        }

        if ((dataArr[linenum,2]) !~ /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/){
        printf "Failed 2nd b validation"
        exit 1
        }
    }

    #verify coulmn 3
    for(linenum = 1; linenum <nr; linenum++) {
        if (length(dataArr[linenum,3]) == 0){
        printf "Failed 3rd a validation"
        exit 1

        }
        # has to be either S or E
        if ((dataArr[linenum,3]) !~ /^[SE]$/){
        printf "Failed 3rd b validation"
        exit 1
        }
    }

    #verify coulmn 4
    for(linenum = 1; linenum <nr; linenum++) {
        #lenght has to between 9 AND 11
        if ((length(dataArr[linenum,4])) < 9 || (length(dataArr[linenum,4]) > 11)){
        printf "Failed 4th validation"
        exit 1
        }
    }

}' "$file"

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
       # "good" status
       mv ${file} test1/goodFile
else
    # "bad" status
    mv ${file} test1/badFile
fi
```

done

Comment: `dataArr[++nr,i]` is a bug. Use the built-in `NR` instead (and deal with the missing entries appropriately), or move the increment outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @Tom Fenech could you expand on how to use built in NR? not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean that `NR` is a built-in variable whose value is the current record number and that you can use it as part of your array index: `dataArr[NR,i]`. The issue with this is that for some values of `NR`, there will be no `dataArr[NR,i]` due to the `next` statement skipping some lines. To use it you would have to add a check into the `for` loop in your `END` block for empty array elements (checking the first one might suffice). The alternative is simpler - just move `++nr` to before the loop and use `dataArr[nr,i]`.

Comment: @TomFenech okay i will go with the alternative, would this be what you suggested in code?{ ++nr  for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) dataArr[nr,i] = $i }? I am sorry but i am new to awk and shell scriptting

Comment: just put a semi-colon between `++nr` and `for` -> `++nr; for ...`. Also in your posted script change `NR = 1` to `NR == 1` for comparison instead of assignment. It's not obvious why you're storing each file in an array and validating in the END section though rather than just validating as the file is read.

Comment: @Ed Morton thank you for the corrections, and as to answer your question. The script is to validate coulmns individualy, if the column is a validated correctly it moves on to the next column otherwise if the first coulmn is bad we skip the remaning 3 columns,send that file to bad direcotory and move on to the next .csv (REPEAT) this is to save time instead of parsing an entire record, just check a field down the column

Comment: That's fine but it doesn't explain why you're storing them all in an array and then checking them in the END section.

Comment: hmm i am not sure either i followed a pre defined structure would there be any changes you would suggest?

Comment: I posted an answer to show how to do what you appear to want (i.e. report any column-1 failures before any column-2 failures) without saving the whole file in an array. If you really don't care which order the check failures are reported you could just report the error wherever it occurs and exit there and the result would be more efficient.

Comment: This code shows a basic mis-understanding of how to use `awk`. Loading every line of a file into an array, and then iterating over the array within the `END { }` block is counter to the way `awk` was designed to run, and much less efficient (at least in memory consumption) than the line-by-line validation that `awk` was designed to provide the capability for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to save the file in an array, all you need is:

```
awk -F',' '                       
# skip the header and blank lines
NR == 1 || NF == 0 {next}

$1 == "" { fails1++ }
$2 == "" { fails2a++ }
$2 !~ /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/) { fails2b++ }
$3 == "" { fails3a++ }
$3 !~ /^[SE]$/ { fails3b++ }
length($4) < 9 || length($4) > 11 { fails4++ }

END {
    if (fails1)  { print "Failed 1st validation"; exit 1 }
    if (fails2a) { print "Failed 2nd a validation"; exit 1 }
    if (fails2b) { print "Failed 2nd b validation"; exit 1 }
    if (fails3a) { print "Failed 3rd a validation"; exit 1 }
    if (fails3b) { print "Failed 3rd b validation"; exit 1 }
    if (fails4)  { print "Failed 4th validation"; exit 1 }

}' "$file"
```

To print the failure messages to stderr instead of stdout, btw, would portably be:

```
if (fails4)  { print "Failed 4th validation" | "cat>&2"; exit 1 }
```

Here's the version if you don't care which error is reported first when the file contains multiple errors:

```
awk -F',' '

# skip the header and blank lines
NR == 1 || NF == 0 {next}

$1 == "" { print "Failed 1st validation"; exit 1 }
$2 == "" { print "Failed 2nd a validation"; exit 1 }
$2 !~ /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/) { print "Failed 2nd b validation"; exit 1 }
$3 == "" { print "Failed 3rd a validation"; exit 1 }
$3 !~ /^[SE]$/ { print "Failed 3rd b validation"; exit 1 }
length($4) < 9 || length($4) > 11 { print "Failed 4th validation"; exit 1 }

' "$file"
```

Comment: holy moly that is really condense and easy to follow!

Comment: If you don't care what order the errors are reported when your file contains multiple errors it's even more condense and easy to follow and it's more efficient when there are errors since it exits when the first error is hit. I added an example of that to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you by far the most through answer received!

Comment: I provided essentially this same answer back when this question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485421/a-modification-of-this-script-in-shell), although at that point the goal seemed to be exiting immediately on a validation failure instead of counting various types of failures...

Comment: Hmm, indeed. Hopefully the OP has now collected enough similar answers to the same question that (s)he can stop asking :-).

Comment: quick question what exactly does the { fails4++ } portion mean?

Comment: Increment a variable named `fails4`. So if any $4 ever meets the error criteria then `fails4` gets a non-zero value, but if all `$4`s pass the test then `fails4` is never incremented and so has value zero/null in the END section.